# how to completely remove eclipse, Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse

I'm running *BackBox* linux

I installed eclipse IDE for C/C++ by downloading it from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/m7/eclipse-ide-linux-developers

i removed eclipse using  `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge eclipse`

and then i executed `sudo find / -name *[E,e]clipse* -exec sudo rm -rf {} \;`

now when i do find (with sudo) on *[E,e]clipse* i get `find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied`

and when i search for eclipse in the search bar i still see an icon of eclipse

[image]

also Eclipse is still there in the in the apps list

[image]

i'm seeking to understand why is this happening and how to completely remove it

Answer (score 0):

You were almost done,run this :

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*
 rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```

this should remove all dependencies & packages for eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands:

```
 sudo apt-get purge eclipse*

sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*

rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```

This will uninstall the dependencies and related packages that were installed along with eclipse. This should do the trick.